# onChartFling never called in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have problem that onChartFling method is never called in my LineChart or BarChart. All other methods from OnChartGestureListener are called correctly, but these not. I put a breakpoint alo int BarLineChartTouchListener. Not called also.

Or is they any other way how to detect end of scrollin on fling ?
onChartTranslate is called multiple times, is it possible to find out if onChartTranslate was called when fling stopped ?

Comment: Have you tried the example project? Does it work there?

Comment: So it is called only when chart is not zoomed, but all data visible. (it is not really a fling in this case, just a try to fling) . In case when zoomed and there is a move in chart, it is not called.

Answer (score 1):

The author says, the way to solve this is to modify the library:

"The reason therefore is, that I do not want to permanently recognize a fling-gesture or single tap when the chart is zoomed in and panned / dragged.
Therefore, gestures do not work in zoomed mode.
If you want to disable this, you will have to modify the library."

These lines should be modified:

```
if(mTouchMode == NONE) { // remove the if
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Code for changing is here: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/405

Answer (score 1):

This bug was fixed on the [AppDevNext fork](https://github.com/AppDevNext/AndroidChart). Simply set `isFlingEnabled` to true to get callbacks for `onChartFling`